# Authenticating unique human identities

Tags: authentication

I want all users to be verified as unique individual real-world self-sovereign human identities who are not personally identifiable. No bot/AI users are allowed. Every human has the right to play, but only one-human-to-one-identity is allowed to (prevent Cybil attacks). This must be done without third party centralized authentication services, such as X.509 CAs, ACTIVE Directory, Google, or Facebook, etc. Is a cryptographic hash of biometric data a solution? An example application would be global UBI crypto payments.

Is there a trade-off? As an analogy, consider the distributed data store CAP theorem: impossible to simultaneously support more than two out of three guarantees for distributed data: Consistency, Availability, and Partition Tolerance.

Perhaps there is a similar trade-off for authentication: impossible to simultaneously support more than two out of three guarantees for users: Uniqueness (one-to-one where each account represents a single user and each user can have only one account), Anonymity (each user is not personally identifiable in  the physical world), and Humanessence (every user is a human rather than an AI).